# GetAllNetworkInterfaces takes some trash

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` to take my network interfaces,

then I trying to take my MAC addreses (`NetInterf[i].GetPhysicalAddress()`)

and it takes me my real interfaces and some trash:

```
[0]: ""
[1]: "00E018998877"
[2]: "001F3C0B4F5D"      
[3]: ""
[4]: "00000000000000E0"
[5]: "00000000000000E0"
[6]: "00000000000000E0"
[7]: "00000000000000E0"
```

[1] and [2] my real MAC adress but other is wrong,
MAC addres must have 6 bytes, isn't?

In program I am filtering with such condition

```
if (NetInterf[i].GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes().Length == 6)
```

I'm doing right? Because I can't find anything about it in MSDN.

Comment: I assume that if you call `GetIPProperties` the other interfaces will be different from those with the expected MAC addresses.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx

Comment: What does the NetworkInterfaceType property return for the respective interfaces?

Comment: @Filip, as I know it returns `Tunnel` for MACs like "00000000000000E0".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more clear way to get all real interfaces will be to use **WMI**. You can retrieve all network adapters information from the [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class. To determine whether the adapter is a physical or a logical adapter need to check `PhysicalAdapter` property. Here is example:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\cimv2");
scope.Connect();
var query = new ObjectQuery(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE PhysicalAdapter = True");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

var networkInterfaces = searcher.Get();
foreach (var networkInterface in networkInterfaces)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", networkInterface["MACAddress"], networkInterface["Name"]));
}
```

Using `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` you can't determine that for sure.